# Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near ")": syntax error

Tags: php, sqlite

*I don't know the reason of this warning, I have checked the code a lot of times on the web,and I don't find a syntax error.*

```
Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near ")": syntax error in     C:\xampp\htdocs\marcadoresOnline\instalacion.php on line 19
```

*Here's the code.*

```
<?php
$conexion = new sqlite3 ('Favoritos.db');
if(!$conexion){echo $conexion->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {echo "Base de datos abierta/creada exitosamente.\n";
   }

$consulta = <<<SQL
  CREATE TABLE favoritos (
    usuario Char()40 NOT NULL,
    contrasena Char(40) NOT NULL,
    titulo Char(40) NOT NULL,
    direccion Char(100) NOT NULL,
    categoria Char(40),
    comentario Char(200),
    valoracion Int
    );
SQL;

$resultado = $conexion-> exec($consulta);
   if(!$resultado){ echo $conexion-> lastErrorMsg();}
    else { echo "Tabla creada exitosamente.\n";
   }

$conexion->close();
```

Comment: ```Char()40``` is wrong, should be ```Char(40)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```sql
usuario Char()40 NOT NULL,
```

should be:

```
usuario Char(40) NOT NULL,
```